# Implement a discrete controller /transfer function with arduino uno

Tags: pwm

i want to implement a discrete transfer function at z domain with arduino UNO.I  know that i must do the inverse z transform and find the difference equation.Afterwards i must use PWM because arduino UNO has not DAC.
Is there anyone who knows about this ?and can help me.... i want a code as an example  .Thank you.

Comment: At the very least your question should include the nature of the inputs, and it would be helpful if you included the equation in the form to be implemented - ie, document every part of the problem *except* the Arduino.

Comment: the reference input is a unit step signal 1 volt.i should use pwm and filters for DAC.Have you got any idea ?